# Comments section on android app

Tags: android, comments

I am planing to build an android app, which will have user posted content and comment on that content. I want to use a ready made solution for the comments, which is also viral.

For example, using Facebook comments for website can do the job. But I am not able to locate such a plugin for Android (java) app.

Is there a way I can do it easily? or should I build my app using phone gap or something like that and use fb comments widget.
Will there be any problem in approval if the app is in phone gap?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IntenseDebate? http://intensedebate.com/

Comment: does that work on mobile platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@happyhardik This might be just what you're looking for: Socialize.  http://www.GetSocialize.com.  SDKs for both iOS and Android.  Integration with Facebook (and soon Twitter).  Let me  know if it's what you wanted!

Comment: disqus mobile theme did the job for me!

Comment: Cool -- we're focusing on using social actions to boost app downloads, so I'd be really interested in knowing how important that functionality is to you.  - DROdio